# How to query remote site settings from Apex

Tags: .net, salesforce, metadata, apex

I have a future method that makes a `callout` to a `.net` application.  Near the top I have the hard coded declaration:

```
private static final String SERVICE_URL = 'https://outside.site.com';
```

which I use later in a `setEndpoint` call on an `HttpRequest` object.

This string occurs in remote site settings - it has to, for it to work.  The value of the string is different between the sandbox and production, but the name of the remote site setting object is the same - 'Broker'.  I would like to eliminate this hard coded string and use the name 'Broker' to find the remote site setting object and set the endpoint to its URL - one less thing to worry about when moving between sandbox and production.

Although I see many examples of how to create a remote site setting using metadata or tooling, I have found no examples of how to query one, just dozens of other people asking how to do it.

What is the best, simplest way to eliminate this hard code?

Answer (score 0):

Remote sites are a metadata object, so you can't access them directly via a SOQL/APEX. This is a security feature to make sure that call outs aren't hitting sites that are not intended to be secure ie sending your secure data outside of your org without your control.

If this were a data object and could be managed via SOQL/Apex someone could maliciously insert a row and then pass all your data from SF to their site.

My suggestion here is to add BOTH base domains eg `example.com` and then either use a custom object or similar to manage the full urls.

Comment: There are examples online of how to use the metadata api to create a remote site setting from Apex or javascript.  If it's possible to do that, which as you say is dangerous, it should be possible to read an existing one, right?

I looked at a custom object and how to force it to be a singleton.   Pros: also supports default selections on lookups.  Cons: has to be manually synched.

Putting both names in the remote site settings - still have hard code to know which to use, and makes it possible for production to send messages to test, or vice versa.

Comment: However, your suggestions did give me another idea: is it possible to get the current site URL, or some kind of "sandbox" flag, from Apex?

Comment: Here's a class that detects the edition of SF and whether it's a sandbox.

http://www.michaelforce.org/recipeView?id=a0Ga000000Ekp65EAB

Unfortunately, it appears almost untestable, or at least impossible to get 75% coverage on it.  Still, it's an option if nothing else appears.

Comment: Yep that's actually how we do it on our codebase, we use the above isSandbox utility and select our endpoint based on it.